# Python Qt QLineEdit weird encoding

Tags: python, encoding, pyqt, qlineedit

I have a situation that has me puzzled. I have a QLineEdit in my interface so when I populate it with the following text  '    (it's aramaic) and I have the correct fonts installed on my machine so I can see the fonts in browsers and all but these fonts I had to install then myself so you might see some weird chars.

```
self.editor = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
self.editor.setText( '   )
```

so in the editor field in the ui I can see the text correctly but when I try to re-extract that text I get something weird:

```
editor_text = self.editor.text()
```

here I get an exception:

```
print(editor_text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud802' in position 0:     
surrogates not allowed

pprint(editor_text)
"\ud802\udc40\ud802\udc4c\ud802\udc53 \ud802\udc4a\ud802\udc53' "
'\ud802\udc53\ud802\udc41 '
'\ud802\udc40\ud802\udc41\ud802\udc53\ud802\udc44\ud802\udc4c '
'\ud802\udc4f\ud802\udc4b'
```

I tried doing:

```
editor_text = self.editor.text().encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogateescape')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud802' in position 0:    
surrogates not allowed
```

What could I do to fix this, thanks

EDIT:

I have of course added the header

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add this to the source header:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   ```

   You can read this thread: [PEP Index](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)
2. In your aramaic character string, add 'u' to the above Python string to use in unicode mode like this:

   ```
   u' ܐܪܡܝܐ‎ '
   ```

   or

   ```
   u'Unicode String'
   ```

Completed code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class exampleQMainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()
        testQLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        testQLineEdit.setText(u'ܐܪܡܝܐ‎')
        print testQLineEdit.text()
        self.setCentralWidget(testQLineEdit)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = exampleQMainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can get variables from somewhere else like this:

```
text = u'ܐܪܡܝܐ‎'
testQLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
testQLineEdit.setText(text)
print testQLineEdit.text()
```

To force the string to Unicode, you can use `unicode(String)`.

This is the test type of output to return text:

```
>> print type(unicode(testQLineEdit.text()))
<type 'unicode'>

>> print type(testQLineEdit.text())
<class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>

>> print type(testQLineEdit.text().toUtf8())
<class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray'>
```

All conditions can print in the console.

Comment: Thanks I already had the source header but for your answer 2 how can do it if I have text='ܐܪܡܝܐ‎'  testQLineEdit.setText(utext) u text gives error, I cannot put the string directly as you say as it comes as variable from somewhere else

Comment: Please use 'u' in declare variable like this;
text = u'ܐܪܡܝܐ‎';
testQLineEdit.setText(utext);

Comment: sorry i expressed myself wrong, I actually don't declare the variable var=u'ܐܪܡܝܐ‎' I get the text from other method var=testQLineEdit.text(). How can I add the u once the string is already created? something like var2=u+var or var2=u+str(var)

Comment: Actually, if you add source header coding: utf-8 it can be read you  aramaic character. If can't read, you can force string in Unicode string like this; var=unicode(testQLineEdit.text());

Comment: thanks a lot but unfortunately it does not work, before populating the string in QLineEdit, the string is printed fine, after populating the QLineEdit and extracting it from QLineEdit the string gets lost in translation. Also the QLineEdit doesn't respect the texte orientation (Right to left)

Comment: Sorry for I can help anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was

```
print unicode(testQLineEdit.text())
```